# Expose AWS Lambda function with API Gateway with bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have error in my bash script for publishing lambda funcs with api gateway.
You can find script here https://gist.github.com/goforbroke1006/7a6c86470a8465ec2302f13d4455094d

If I create resource + method + intergation via web AWS console interface then everything works fine:

[image: working sample]

but if I use bash script I will get this

[image]

recognized lambda function empty and API method test returns

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

What's wrong with this script?
Maybe I have invalid func integration URL. I have no idea how to build this url or where I can copy it, so I use this template

```
arn:aws:apigateway:${REGION_NAME_WHAT_I_USE_4_LAMBDA_AND_API}:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/${FUNCTION_ARN_URL_COPIED_ON_EDIT_FUNC_PANEL_IN_AWS_CONSOLE}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Lambda function has an API Gateway trigger ?

The console adds proper authorization to let API Gateway invoke the Lambda function, but if you do it programatically, you also need to add the authorization at Lambda level

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html

Also, we do not recommend to use bash to deploy infrastructure as it does not support updates or delete.  Use [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html) or [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) instead